# Why cant chrome also delete my search bar?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

So when I press control + H and clear all my history, it shows everything is clear!
BUT!, when I type something like re on the search bar, it shows my previous searches. This shouldn't happen because I have cleared all my history!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are clearing just the history. To do a more through wipe, you will want to clear all browsing data with **CTRL + SHIFT + DEL**

Make sure to select 'clear saved autofill form data' along with the browsing history checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

For a more precise approach (wiping browser history and autofill form data is a bit of a blanket solution), you can press **down arrow** when these suggestions appear below the address bar, and press **DEL** on specific instances.